# KDE4 configuration via file?

Tags: kde4

For quite some time I've got the following problem: on my desktop I placed a special folder view app (see screenshot). I cannot resize or move it in any way when the apps/ bars are in unlocked mode.

I find the overall configuration a bit unhandy - is it somehow possible to configure one's desktop in a text-based fashion? Is there some other way to "debug" the desktop?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is your question how to move the folder view when you lock your widgets?

Comment: Hello @jokerdino. Actually no. It appears there occured a visualisation bug as I could not resize/ relocate the applet in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually all applets on the desktop can be modified within this file.
This helped also with removing the corrupted folderview-plasmoid from the desktop.

> `~/.kde/share/config/plasma-desktop-appletsrc`